# How to add transition to this line chart D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I created this Line chart using D3.but I cannot add the transition of drawing the line to this.Ive tried many different ways but each time d3 throws an error.Maybe my way of drawing the path is wrong and thats why I cant add a transition.A help would be much appreciated.Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3wsLjfgu/

```
d3.json("https://cors.io/?
https://canvasjs.com/data/gallery/javascript/daily-sales-data.json", 
function (dataArr) {

let margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataArr));

let svg = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

let g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

let x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width - (margin.right)]);

let y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

let line = d3.line()
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.units); });

let all = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let stringDate = new Date(data[i].date);
    all.push({ date: stringDate, units: data[i].units })
}

x.domain(d3.extent(all, function (d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(all, d => d.units)]);

g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")

g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))


g.append("path")
    .datum(all)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

g.selectAll("dot")
    .data(all)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.date) })
    .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.units) })
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(100)
            .attr("r", 12)

    })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(100)
            .attr("r", 6);
    })
    .append("title")
    .append("text")
    .text(d => d.units)

 })
```

Comment: "but I cannot add the transition of drawing the line to this", can you define exactly the transition you want for your line ?

Comment: @PierreCapo the basic animation of drawing the line from left to right

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768908/gerardo-furtado Ive tried as this answer shows but the result is the same.The same error comes up

Comment: I made this jsfiddle for you before it was marked as duplicate : https://jsfiddle.net/3wsLjfgu/22/

Comment: @PierreCapo Yeah It works.Cheers mate :)